# A list of divs to javascript array (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering how i can convert a list of html divs into a javascript array?
So here is the html code i have

```
<div class="colors">
    <div>Red</div>
    <div>Blue</div>
    <div>Orange</div>
    <div>Green</div>
</div>
```

so now i want to convert the divs that is inside the first div to a javascript array. How can i do this?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: Well i want a javascript array something like var colors = ["<div>Red</div>", "<div>Blue</div>", "<div>Orange</div>", "<div>Green</div>"];

Comment: Use `document.getElementByClass()` method.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("colors")[0].children;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `document.querySelectorAll` and then create an array from them through `Array.from` method:

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.colors div')));
```

```html
<div class="colors">
    <div>Red</div>
    <div>Blue</div>
    <div>Orange</div>
    <div>Green</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the rest of my javascript code...
function colors() {
  var myArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.colors div'))
  var rand = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
  document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = rand;
}

Comment: are you sure you have a container with class `food` and div elements inside? above you added a code where the class is `colors`

Comment: and what "does not seem to work" means? what's the issue?

Comment: Well i changed to colors now. But my original code is with food. But i just used colors as an example here...

Comment: I have a button in the html code. When i click it does not return anything

Comment: you are changing your question at run time :) your question was how to get an array of these html ements, and you got it. Now what you are saying above is a different issue. I need to see your code to understand where is the issue

Comment: Okay. I link you my pen. Hopefully that will be easier for you :)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwgGWY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186499/discussion-between-quirimmo-and-tim-levinsson).

Comment: @TimLevinsson - You are collecting HTMLElements into an array. You are not collecting plain text i.e `<div>Red</div>`, but are instead collecting divs that may or may not (they always do here) contain some text. As such, `document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = rand;` will print garbage onto the screen, in fact it will say: `[object HTMLDivElement]`. What you instead meant to do was `<div id='output'><div>Red</div></div>` _or_ `<div id='output'>Red</div>` If it's the latter - don't put elements into the array, put the txt they contain in there then put the contents of an element 2 screen

Comment: If it's the former, don't put `rand` in there, put `rand.outerHTML` there. ;)

Comment: @enhzflep it looks like this is what he wants, if you read his comments below the question. Then you can simply do `rand.innerText` and get back the text of the div

Comment: @quirimmo - I've presented 2 different options. Forgive me, but your comment is no more clear to me than someone that says "Yes" when asked if they'd like tea or coffee. Without specifying _which_ option, the whole exchange seems not to be effective.

Comment: @enhzflep `document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML = rand.innerText;` will print the content of the div, not `[object HTMLDivElement]`. Is it more clear now? And he wants an array of the HTML elements, and then access the text as shown above (`innerText`)

Comment: @quirimmo - I suppose so. (not for lack of your articulate description, but for the stunning silence from the OP) There's a +1 from me on your answer, since you used `Array.from` instead of the much more cryptic `[...` notation.

Comment: @enhzflep I got you and I agree with you, I totally agree with you :) I would have saved the texts rather than the div elements, but it looks like this is what he wants... as they say about customers, the op is always right :)

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy to do - convert the NodeList of the divs to an array, then map the `innerText`:

```js
 

var divArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".color div"));
divArray = divArray.map(e => e.innerText);

console.log(divArray);
```

```html
 

<div class="colors">
    <div>Red</div>
    <div>Blue</div>
    <div>Orange</div>
    <div>Green</div>
</div>
```

Or if you want the actual div elements - not their text, eliminate this line:

```
divArray = divArray.map(e => e.innerText);
```